# Pairwise subtraction of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

There are two arrays:

```
 $arr1 = array(1,2,3);
 $arr2 = array(0,0,1);
```

I need to make pairwise subtraction of these two arrays. The result for arr1 - arr2 should be:

`$arr3 = array(1,2,2)`.

Do I need to use FOR loop to to this or is there any quicker way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this function?

```
function array_sub_values($arr1, $arr2)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr1 as $k => $val)
        $result[] = $val - $arr2[$k];
    return $result;
}
```

So you can do:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3);
$arr2 = array(0, 0, 1);

$arr3 = array_sub_values($arr1, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers, you could also use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
function sub($x, $y){
    return $x - $y;
}

$arr3 = array_map('sub', $arr1, $arr2);
```