# PHP: filling arrays in multidimensional one to have the same number of elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array with the days of one month grouped by days of the week.

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 15
            [3] => 22
            [4] => 29
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 16
            [3] => 23
            [4] => 30
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 24
            [4] => 31
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 21
            [3] => 28
        )

)
```

As you can see all the arrays have five elements but for the last two that have four.

How can I fill the last two arrays so they can also have five elements?

I'd like to fill them with empty values so when I'm printing an html table it'll print nothing after day 31

Thanks a lot

Comment: what if you'd just fix your printing, instead of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really insist on having the fix for the data isntead of having it for the printing as the comment suggested, then you could use [`array_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) in something like this:

```
$days = array(....) // that's your original array
foreach($days as $key => $val){
    if(count($val)<5)
        $days[$key] = array_pad($val, 5, 0);
}
```

Where `array_pad($val, 5, 0);` fills the array with `0`'s till it reaches length `5`.

Comment: Great! Still, that's less efficient than "fixing the printing" ;-)

Comment: You don't need to loop, just use `array_map`

Comment: @deifwud: Yes, indeed, although people tend to get scared by OR don't get the idea of `array_map`, i.e. [that answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341843/pairwise-subtraction-of-two-arrays/12341940#12341940) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) to do this.

**example**

```
$data = array(
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(3, 4, 5),
    array(4, 9, 10, 11),
    array(1, 3, 5, 7, 8)
);

var_dump(array_map(function($val) { 
  return array_pad($val, 5, ''); 
}, $data));
```

**outputs**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4
      4 => int 5
  1 => 
    array
      0 => int 3
      1 => int 4
      2 => int 5
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 9
      2 => int 10
      3 => int 11
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 3
      2 => int 5
      3 => int 7
      4 => int 8
```

Comment: I'm doing:      $myArray = array_pad($myArray, 5, ''); but nothing changes

Comment: You need to do it on the child arrays

Answer (score 0):

adding values to multid. array using array_push is like so:

```
array_push ($array[1]['something'], "value");
```

in your example:

```
array_push ($array[count($array)][4], 99); 
array_push ($array[count($array)-1][4], 99);
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I know the arrays to be filled are 1 and 2? This is the structure for one month but next month it can be array 3 and 4 the short ones ..

Comment: i edited my answer: use count() and count()-1 to get the last and last-1